# Which diagram is correct?

Tags: chords, acoustic-guitar, self-learning, fretboard

I have the following two diagrams that represent the notes on every fret of a guitar

[image]

[image]

This is the E major chord on the guitar:

[image]

First, there are 7 notes (E, F♯, G♯, A, B, C♯, and D♯) in the E chord but only 6 strings. Second, where are these notes on the fretboard and third, why are the first two diagrams of the fretboard so different?

Comment: "here are 7 notes (E, F♯, G♯, A, B, C♯, and D♯) in the E chord" -- no. Those are the notes of the E major scale. There are 3 notes in an E major triad: E, G#, and B. Also, there is not _one_ "E chord" on the guitar, but many, many different voicings which may be played.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, your assumption of 7 notes refers to **E scale**, not **E chord**. In the chord, there are 3 notes, E G# and B. They're shared between the 6 strings. Each string will play one of those notes, and it becomes apparent which one of each is easiest to reach, while occupying every string. That E chord is known as the 'open E', as it contains open strings as well as fretted. There are many other shapes of E major played on guitar, but all will (or should) contain at least one E, one G# and one B somewhere. They're called inversions and voicings.

The two charts are similar, except the lower one doesn't include alternative note names. A lot of guitar based sites seem to be under the misapprehension that only sharps (#) exist. The upper chart shows both names.

The 'MC' represents 'middle C', more commonly now - or getting that way- C4,

Comment: Give it a bit longer - there might be a better answer that you prefer. It's too early yet !!

Comment: You might want to add that the first chart starts with the first fret (F...), while the second starts with open strings (E...)

Comment: @Marzipanherz - not really - both charts have EADGBE on their left side.

Comment: I meant the first column, next to the column with the string names

Comment: @Marzipanherz that's a great point. That would be very confusing for a new player.

Comment: @Marzipanherz - why not include that in an answer?

Comment: @Tim I don't think that would be enough for an answer. It'd be better to edit it into your answer or into Macpeters answer. Marzipanherz, you can suggest edits for people.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Tim's answer: The Major chord has 3 notes: the 1st, 3rd, and 5th of the scale.  If you look at the different chord types (Minor, 7th), you'll notice they take different parts of the same scale.  This link will show you a description of the different chord types and how they are made up: https://www.edmprod.com/different-chord-types/

Your two diagrams are different for a few reasons:
- second one is color coded (obvious difference)
- first shows the notes, with either name (f# and gb are the same note with different names)
- second favours one note name (only f#). I'm not sure what the numbers there are: maybe what finger you should use?

I found the fretboard a bit cryptic until I tried something, which I recommend you try.  Take a copy of your first diagram (without color), and find every instance of E - that's your root note.  Color it red.  Find every instance of the 3rd (G#) and color them all yellow.  Find every fifth (B), and color it blue.  You will get a clear picture of how notes are distributed in a pattern.  Every scale works the same way, only the roots start elsewhere.  If you play the chord in each different place, you can hear the difference in sound - it's the same chord, but as Tim said, a different voice.

Comment: The numbers in the second diagram appear to be octave numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to learn where the notes are on your fretboard and forget about the diagrams: my advice would be to practice fretboard note ID: it will simply open up your possibilities by making you aware of the notes you're playing (and where!) when you are strumming a chord.

Comment: I don't think that this is bad advice, but some ideas about how to practice "fretboard note ID" would be helpful. For example, play the chromatic scale up and down the neck, spelling the note names, sharps ascending and flats descending. Or, play any scale or arpeggio up and down the neck, spelling note names. Or place your hand anywhere on the neck and have a friend (or computer program or deck of flashcards or whatever) suggest a note name; play all instances of the suggested note which are under your hand. Etc.